# flutter bloc how stop execution loop inside event?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I use a `Provider` with `ChangeNotifier`, but inside it I need to make a `StreamController` that will process the data. For example, let there be a list of sites

```
class ExampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  //list of sites for data processing
  final List<String> _weblinks = [];

  ExampleProvider() {
    
    //Fill in demo data
    _weblinks.add("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    _weblinks.add("https://github.com");
    _weblinks.add("http://microsoft.com");
    
    //subscribe to the stream in the constructor
    eventStream.listen((event) async {
      if (event is StartProcessing) {
        for (var i = 0; i < _weblinks.length; i++) {
          
          //Doing some fake calculations
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
          
          //add the result to the stream
          dataSink.add(_weblinks[i]);
        }
      }

      if (event is FinishProcessing) {}
    });
  }

  final _streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> get dataStream => _streamController.stream;
  StreamSink<String> get dataSink => _streamController.sink;

  final _eventController = StreamController<StreamControllerAction>.broadcast();
  Stream<StreamControllerAction> get eventStream => _eventController.stream;
  StreamSink<StreamControllerAction> get eventSink => _eventController.sink;

}
```

The problem is that the list of sites can be very large and if a data processing thread has started, then I can’t interrupt or cancel it, I cannot stop the execution of the loop, and until the list of sites ends, the thread will be executed. I also cannot use `_streamController.close()` because the stream is inside the `provider`, which is and the stream will be disabled forever, and I would like to reuse it. is there a way to interrupt the execution of a stream if the data is evaluated in a loop?

Full code

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: ExampleProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: MyHomePage(),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<String>(
              initialData: null,
              stream: Provider.of<ExampleProvider>(context, listen: false)
                  .dataStream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                List<Widget> children;
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  children = <Widget>[Text("error")];
                } else {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      children = <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text("processing data"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Provider.of<ExampleProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                .eventSink
                                .add(StartProcessing());
                          },
                        ),
                      ];
                      break;

                    default:
                      {
                        children = <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text("finish"),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                              Text(snapshot.data),
                            ],
                          )
                        ];
                      }
                      break;
                  }
                }

                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: children,
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _weblinks = [];

  ExampleProvider() {
    _weblinks.add("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    _weblinks.add("https://github.com");
    _weblinks.add("http://microsoft.com");

    eventStream.listen((event) async {
      if (event is StartProcessing) {
        for (var i = 0; i < _weblinks.length; i++) {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
          dataSink.add(_weblinks[i]);
        }
      }

      if (event is FinishProcessing) {}
    });
  }

  final _streamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> get dataStream => _streamController.stream;
  StreamSink<String> get dataSink => _streamController.sink;

  final _eventController = StreamController<StreamControllerAction>.broadcast();
  Stream<StreamControllerAction> get eventStream => _eventController.stream;
  StreamSink<StreamControllerAction> get eventSink => _eventController.sink;

 
}

abstract class StreamControllerAction {}

class StartProcessing extends StreamControllerAction {}

class FinishProcessing extends StreamControllerAction {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop listening to eventStream you can save its subscription in a StreamSubscription object and then you will have access to .pause() and .resume().

When you use stream.listen() it returns a StreamSubscription you can save in a variable and use later.

You can read more about it in the documentation https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html

Comment: Maybe I didn’t understand your idea, but I don’t need to stop listening or pause eventStream.

Comment: Alright then in that case I guess I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Sorry my friend :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let's say I'm running an infinite loop in the stream, and I need to interrupt it when I press the button. I don't need to pause it. I don’t need to unsubscribe from it, because I will restart it in the future.